# start npm error (npm install --save-dev webpack)

Tags: npm, webpack

Can you please help me to solve the problem?
I wanted to contribute to rebus project on git hub, so I cloned it, and added a rebus object. 
To run the game locally through linux in virtual machine after installing and updating nodejs and npm. Then, I made `npm start`.
But the result was below.

```
> rebus@1.0.0 start /home/mara/opso/rebus
> webpack-dev-server --mode development

sh: 1: webpack-dev-server: not found

npm ERR! Linux 5.0.0-36-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! rebus@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --mode development`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the rebus@1.0.0 start script 'webpack-dev-server --mode development'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the rebus package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server --mode development
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs rebus
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls rebus
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/mara/opso/rebus/npm-debug.log
```

After searching to solve the problem, I found i had to do `sudo npm install -g webpack-dev-server`
But the error still occurs.

```
/usr/local/bin/webpack-dev-server -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js
npm WARN webpack-dev-server@3.10.1 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ webpack-dev-server@3.10.1
added 400 packages from 272 contributors in 28.25s
```

Can you help me how to solve this problem and do "npm start" successfully?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this dependency

npm install --save-dev webpack

Comment: events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
npm ERR! Linux 5.0.0-36-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! rebus@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --mode development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1    (But it's still same problem)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-dev-server follow this link